# Obtain list of files created by (child) process

Tags: .net, windows, winapi

On Windows, is it possible to get a list of all files a process, that was programmatically started from our application, created while it was/is running?

Are there any .NET or Win32 APIs to do this?

Comment: Not reliably / easy / without a lot of effort. This sounds like an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What problem are you trying to solve with that?

Answer (score 0):

[`FileSystemWatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-7.0) would allow detection of changes, but has no information on which process caused those changes. So the quick answer is no.

[Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) gets this information by added a driver running within the OS kernel.

Comment: Interesting, do you happen to know where I can find more about that driver Process Monitor uses?

Comment: @kwyntes sorry no. A hunt for history of sysinternals might reveal something.